# Input files required to programmatically generate a PKCS#12 certificate

Tags: c, openssl, pkcs#12, pkcs#7, csr

I need to create an application in C to generate a self signed PKCS#12 certificate. I have an application which so far creates a **.csr** and a **.key** file.

I also have a program which creates a PKCS#12 object from a supplied **.key** and **.p7** file. So given that I have a **.csr** and a **.key** file, I assume my next move would be to create a **.p7** file from the **.key** / **.csr** file?

I found a sample application [here](http://www.cs.odu.edu/~cs772/sourcecode/NSwO/EX10-8) which signs or verifies certificates. At the end of the signing process, we have a PKCS7 object. I assume that is the object I need.

However, the sample application gives the following error when I run it with the key I have generated:

```
$ ./sign_and_verify_util sign mykey.key.pem
Error reading signer private key in mykey.key.pem
```

I added the .pem onto the file because I thought that was the issue.

Any shove in the right direction would be a great help and I would really appreciate it!

**Edit**

I just converted mykey.key to mykey.key.pem correctly using:

```
openssl rsa -inform DER -outform PEM -in mykey.key -out mykey.key.pem
```

Now the application I am trying to get the **.p7** file from says:

```
Error reading signer certificate in (null)
```

Comment: I've only done this using the openssl command line tool so take this with a grain of salt but typically a pkcs#12 file contains a certificate and its corresponding private key. I believe the first step would to be generate a self signed certificate file and then combine it. To be consistent, all these files can be in .pem format. The code you provided is failing as it requires the signer's certificate so I assume it cannot handle self signing. So my suggestion is to look into self signing certificates before trying to generate a pkcs#12.

Comment: Just figuring out this now, I am trying to use the command line to convert my .csr file to a .csr.pem, new error is:

`unable to load certificate
3073906888:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:696:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE`

Thanks for the reply though, looks like you were spot on!

Comment: That might be because the .csr is not a certificate itself but a request for a signed certificate. For reference this is how you would generate a self-signed certificate and a corresponding rsa private key: `openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -days 365 -out cacert.pem -outform PEM -subj /CN=test/ -nodes`. This will make two files cacert.pem, and privkey.pem which you could then do `openssl pkcs12 -export -out keycert.p12 -in cacert.pem -inkey privkey.pem` where you'll be prompted to choose a password for the pkcs file. Again not sure how to do it with the C libraries but hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like I can skip making the csr, think that was throwing me off a bit!! Cheers again